# How to make instant redirection in Laravel

Tags: symfony, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

I want to make an instant redirection in my controller in Laravel.

I know I can use

```
public function show($page) 
{   
   return Redirect::url('http://example.com');
}
```

but I want to repeat this code in many controllers adding condition for example I would like to do something like this:

```
public function show($page) 
{
  $totalPages = 100; // here calculating maximum page

  if ($page < 2 || $page > $totalPages)  {
     return Redirect::url('http://example.com');
  }    
  // rest of code here - should be run if condition is false
}
```

but I don't want to repeat code in each controller.

If I try put redirection code in other method (that could exist in base controller) it won't work because it doesn't return anything in main controller:

```
public function show($page) 
{
  $totalPages = 100; // here calculating maximum page
  $this->checkPages($page, $totalPages, 'http://example.com');   

 // rest of code here - should be run if condition is false   
}

public function checkPages($page, $totalPages, $url) 
{
  if ($page < 2 || $page > $totalPages)  {
     return Redirect::url($url);
  }    
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of digging it seems that for this purposes you should use `send()` method from `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation` (Laravel `RedirectResponse` inherits from this class).

So you can modify `checkPages` method this way:

```
public function checkPages($page, $totalPages, $url) 
{
  if ($page < 2 or $page > $totalPages)  {
     Redirect::url($url)->send();
  }    
}
```

and it will make instant redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the results of the method in the base controller.

`return $this->checkPages($page, $totalPages, 'http://example.com');`

Comment: I know that. But this method doesn't always return redirection so I would need to add if code to all controllers where I would like to use this method

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably suggest that your `checkPages` method is trying to do too much. Would I expect `checkPages` (which maybe should be `validatePageNumber()` or similar) to return a **redirect**? No, I'd expect it to return `true` or `false`.

That gives you this as your logic:

```
/**
 * Make sure the current page is between 1 and $lastPage
 *
 * @param int $page
 * @param int $lastPage
 * @return bool
 */
protected function validatePageNumber( $page, $lastPage ) {
    return $page < 2 || $page > $lastPage;
}
```

and now your controller logic is trivial:

```
public function show( $page ) {
    $totalPages = 100;
    if ( ! $this->validatePageNumber( $page, $totalPages ) ) {
        return Redirect::url( 'http://example.com' );
    }   

    // rest of code here - should be run if condition is false   
}
```

---

Now if we use quasi-English to read your code, you have a public method `show($page)` which shows a page: it sets the total number of pages, checks that `$page` is valid, and if not, redirects somewhere. All of this is control logic, and only control logic, which is what a controller should be doing.

Your `validatePageNumber()` can now be abstracted into a model, or better yet, a ServiceProvider, and it does one job: validates that a number is between 1 and `n`.

Comment: No, this `show` method does not show page. It gets page parameter to pagination in this case. I know that controller logic is trivial here but in this case this `if` statement have to be repeated in many controllers which is not DRY. And yes, I have method `isValidPage` too and my real `checkPage` method look like this: `if (!$this->isValidPage($page, $pages)) { Redirect::to($url)->send(); }`. I also believe this method cannot be extracted to ServiceProvider because the total number of pages is calculated in controller - depending on conditions data may be gathered using different conditions.