# Session Validation check in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on Laravel. I want to redirect to login page if session is not set. but its still not working. Here is my code.

```
public function __construct()
{
   if(!Session::has('id'))
   {
       return Redirect::to('');
   }
}
```

Comment: still if i try to run home function under same controller, it run and give me error because session is not set can anyone tell me whats the problem there

Comment: Returning within a constructor will not work. Use laravel before filters instead. [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try here with making instant redirection:

```
public function __construct()
{
   if(!Session::has('id'))
   {
       Redirect::to('')->send();
   }
}
```

It seems work also when using in constructor. I described it also at [How to make instant redirection in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801911/how-to-make-instant-redirection-in-laravel)

Comment: can to tell me what is the difference between both route and why we use second route.                                                                1. Route::get('login', 'webcontroller@login');
2. Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login','uses'=>'webcontroller@login'));

Comment: @Tariqhussain The second one is named route. It's better to use it because you will be able to change url in future without a problem

Comment: 1. Route::get('login', 'webcontroller@login'); => Route::get('newname'=>'webcontroller@login');                                                                                                     2. Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login','uses'=>'webcontroller@login')); =>  Route::get('newname', array('as' => 'login','uses'=>'webcontroller@login'));                             i changed url in both i think both will work then what the difference between both ?

Comment: @Tariqhussain If you have new question you should ask one as separate question